# gmaps-autocomplete-rails write Lang + Long written to hidden field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

I'm hoping someone can help me, I have the gmaps-autocomplete-rails working fine, but I'm stumped on how to write the Longitude and Latitude to a hidden field for a form submission.

I can write it to a  just can't make heads or tails of this part of the guide

The following default methods can be replaced by configuration:

positionOutputter
updateUI
updateMap
These methods are used to control how the gmaps data is used to update the UI on the page, such as the position output and map position update. Customize these needed.

The default logic (taken from GmapsCompleterDefaultAssist) is:

```
 defaultUpdateMap: (geometry) -> 
    map     = @map
    marker  = @marker

    map.fitBounds(geometry.viewport) if map
    marker.setPosition(geometry.location) if marker

  # fill in the UI elements with new position data
  defaultUpdateUI: (address, latLng) ->
    $(@inputField).autocomplete 'close'

    @debug 'country', @country

    updateAdr = address.replace ', ' + @country, ''
    updateAdr = address

    @debug 'updateAdr', updateAdr

    $(@inputField).val updateAdr
    @positionOutputter latLng

  defaultPositionOutputter: (latLng) ->
    $('#gmaps-output-latitude').html latLng.lat()
    $('#gmaps-output-longitude').html latLng.lng()
```

All I think I need to do is change that last part to be .val rather than .html

but where and how this gets added to a coffeescript I'm lost.

If I write directly to the hidden fields I get the following:

```
<input id="gmaps-output-longitude" type="hidden" name="submission[longitude]">-019019992</input>
```

Which obviously doesn't get passed in the form as it's not the value=""

I've tried writing to a span and doing an on change to write to the hidden vield  but no joy there either.

```
jQuery ->

    completer = new GmapsCompleter
      inputField: '#gmaps-input-address'
      errorField: '#gmaps-error'

    completer.autoCompleteInit
      country: "us"


    $('#gmaps-output-longitude').on('change', updateChange)

updateChange = ->
  $('#submission_longitude').val($('#gmaps-output-longitude'))
  $('#submission_latitude').val($('#gmaps-output-latitude'))
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out I'd missed a bit, but for future reference to override the default behaviour you need to include the assist option and reference with a coffeescript extend.

This is my final working coffeescript all in one file, just make sure you outdent the class.

```
jQuery ->
  completer = new GmapsCompleter
    inputField: '#gmaps-input-address'
    errorField: '#gmaps-error'
    assist: MyCompleterAssist


  completer.autoCompleteInit
    country: "us"



class MyCompleterAssist extends GmapsCompleterDefaultAssist
  positionOutputter: (latLng) ->
   $('#gmaps-output-latitude').val latLng.lat()
   $('#gmaps-output-longitude').val latLng.lng()
```

Comment: Strange. With your implementation I get "SyntaxError: [stdin]:11:14: unexpected ." error. When I remove the "assist: MyCompleterAssist" line, error is gone. What may be wrong?

Comment: No indentation errors? Did you get to the bottom of it? Sorry for the slow reply.